# Java Fibonacci /Math Involvement/No Packages

Tags: java, math, recursion, fibonacci, factorial

I've been having trouble with this problem where:

I have to write a recursive method that solves a multiplication problem of any two integers, whether positive or negative.

before this I wrote a method that is a part of a sequence and another method that did the same thing as my problem but it is only for positive numbers:

I'm stuck at Fib3,

where I am supposed to multiply -7 by 8 but,

since B is greater than 0,

it automatically inputs A which is just -7 (result should be -56)

Here is my Code:

```
public class P4_Icel_Murad_Fibonacci
{
   private int N;
   private int result;
   private int A; 
   private int B;
   private int result2;
   private int result3;
    P4_Icel_Murad_Fibonacci(){
  }
   int Fib1(int N){
     if (N == 1 || N == 0){
        return N;
        }else if (N >= 1){
            result = Fib1(N-1) + Fib1(N-2);
            result = Fib1(N-1) + Fib1(N-2);
            result = Fib1(N-1) + Fib1(N-2);
            result = Fib1(N-1) + Fib1(N-2);
        }
     return result;
  }
  int Fib2(int A, int B){
      if ( A == 1 || B == 1){
          return A;
        }else if ( A >= 0 && B >= 0){
          result2 =  (A + 2) * Fib2(A-3,B);
        }
        return result2;
    }
  int Fib3(int A, int B){
      if ( A >= 0 || B >= 0){
          return A;
        }else if ( A < 0 || B < 0){
          result3 =  (A) * Fib3(A-3,B);
        }
        return result3;
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
public class Driver
{   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        P4_Icel_Murad_Fibonacci create = new P4_Icel_Murad_Fibonacci();
        System.out.println("Fib(11) = " + create.Fib1(11));
        System.out.println("7 * 8 = " + create.Fib2(7,8));
        System.out.println("-7 * 8 = " + create.Fib3(-7,8));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? what is your exact problem or the stacktrace that you are struggeling with?

Comment: @KevinEsche I'm stuck at Fib3, where I am supposed to multiply -7 by 8 but, since B is greater than 0, it automatically inputs A which is just -7.

Comment: if ( A >= 0 || B >= 0){
          return A;  ---> i dont see why you are surprised to have (-7,8)--> -7

Comment: @ErwanC. I know that's problem but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @Murad Muhammed Icel what is the expected result ?

Comment: @ErwanC.  it supposed to be -54

Comment: Are you actually trying to do the fibunacci, or just recursive multiplication by adding the values?

Comment: @KevinEsche recursive multiplication.

Comment: @MuradMuhammedIcel as i see it you are building the sum of the fibunacci up to the eight´s run, since 8 * 7 doesn´t equal 54.

Comment: @KevinEsche oops I meant -56

Comment: result3 =  (A) * Fib3(A-3,B) with (-7,8) it is divergent

Comment: @ErwanC. I'm confused, what do you mean divergent?

Comment: with your actual code it returns A and if you want to invert conditions and have if ( A < 0 || B < 0) first, you ll have an infinite loop

Comment: @ErwanC. ohh I think I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether the OP has correctly described the problem.

I would do something like:

```
int multiply(int a, int b) {
    if(b==0){
        return 0;
    } else if (b > 0){
        return a + multiply(a, b-1)
    } else { // b < 0; 
        return -a + multiply(a, b+1)
    }
}
```

That is recursive, handles both positive and negative numbers. Its not very efficient really, you might like to insure that abs(b) is less than abs(a) so you might add a line like:

```
if( abs(a) < abs (b)){
   return multiply(b,a)
}
```

first thing to at least insure that it doesn't do a million iterations for 0 * 1,000,000.

Obviously this is a terrible way to do multiplication but it seems to answer the OP's problem as described.

Answer (score -2):

The truth tables of OR statements seem to be your problem. 
Since your code states

```
 if ( A >= 0 || B >= 0){
           return A;
```

It's going to return A because the OR condition of B >= 0 is being satisfied.
Perhaps think of a clearer IF statement?

Comment: already said in comment and you only point out an error OP knows. You dont really help him to get the expected result